# Drop column names using wild card from a bigquery table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to create a new table from an existing one (in bigquery), excluding those columns where the column name is ending with '_scl'. Using except is not feasible since there are almost 1000+ column names that end with _scl. Is there a way to use wild card to eliminate such columns? Or any other way?

Comment: You should add sample data and expected output.

Comment: You will need to write a script outside BigQuery for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do to filter/remove/eliminate columns on the existing table on BigQuery Interface (UI). Nevertheless, I think it is possible to do this automatically with a python script or other programming language.

Anyway, I want to show you how to exclude those columns and I provide queries to create a table without columns name that you will not include (check column *ctas_table_query*).

```
WITH
  schema_table_columns AS (
  SELECT
    STRING_AGG(column_name, ", "
    ORDER BY
      ordinal_position ASC) AS columns_only,
    STRING_AGG(CONCAT('  ', column_name), ", \n"
    ORDER BY
      ordinal_position ASC) AS columns_with_space,
    CONCAT(table_schema, '.', table_name) AS schema_table_name
  FROM
   "put_your_project_id_here"."put_your_dataset_here".INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE
    table_name="put_your_table_name_here"
    AND column_name NOT LIKE '__put_your_condition_here'
  AND is_hidden = 'NO'
  GROUP BY
    schema_table_name)
SELECT
  concat ('CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE \n  ',
    RESULT.schema_table_name,
    ' AS \nSELECT \n',
    RESULT.columns_with_space,
    '\nFROM \n  ',
    RESULT.schema_table_name) AS ctas_table_query,
  RESULT.columns_only
FROM
  schema_table_columns AS RESULT
```

Comment: I have tried this suggestion and it works perfectly for small tables. You just need to modify the name of the resultant table in case you do not want to overwrite your own. Not sure how it will perform for big tables with a lot of columns as the one Arya was talking about. @Arya could you try this solution and let us know how it performed?